# How do generate child key for AngularFireDatabase?

Tags: angular5, angularfire5

I have pattern:

```
export class Items {
  key: string;
  item: string;
  childItems: {key: string; item: string; };
}
```

And have some Service is generating parent key:

```
export class OptionService {
  private dbPath = '/items';
  itemsRef: AngularFireList<Items> = null;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.itemsRef = db.list(this.dbPath);
  }

  createItem(item: Items): void {
    this.itemsRef.push(item);
}
```

How do may generate key in "childItems"? I need make unique key for this element when I will add property value. Please help me find resolve.